# Color Reference: Where do you get your ideas?

Tags: user-interface, colors

I am the only dev in a very small IT shop and as such I have no one to turn to when it comes to the look of my applications. I am left to my own devices as to what looks good with what and what matches what.

This got me wondering, where do other programmers get their color ideas?

***Am I the only programmer who likes all of his apps in grayscale?***

What are some sites, books, apps, tips and tricks to giving your **custom built application** some vibrance and life that end users **MIGHT** actually appreciate?

Comment: Lol, I tend to make everything in grayscale too.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with colors?

Comment: I like it that the 'colors' tag isn't colorful.

Comment: Should I reword this slightly and turn it in to a community-wiki or is it to late for that and it will just be confusing?  I didn't think I would get this kind of response.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest Adobe's [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/).  You can bring in an image, like a logo, and have it suggest a set of 5 colors that work well together.  Lots of different options.  Also lets you save your palettes.  You can then browse through other people's color combinations.

Comment: oh no, i was a second too slow!

Comment: One of the nice things about kuler is that it's integrated into a lot of the adobe applications - I know it's available in illustrator, but I think they've recently added it to flash, photoshop... probably a few others, which makes it super easy to apply and change color themes, when designing an application.

Answer (score 11):

I too prefer my apps in greyscale, although a hint of colour doesn't hurt. For example, meta.stackoverflow.com looks kinda weird to me after spending a lot of time on stackoverflow. If you're looking for just colour ideas, I'd check out these sites for colour suggestions:

http://www.colourlovers.com/

http://kuler.adobe.com/

For typeography:
http://webtypography.net/

Maybe also pick up some good design books? (I like this one [http://www.amazon.com/Designer-Grid-Lucienne-Roberts/dp/2880466784](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2880466784))

Answer (score 5):

Contrast is one of those things that can make or break the design of a site.  Some colors don't go well together.  Red text on a green background, for example, may seem like it'd be a high contrast and easy to read combination, but it's not.  And it's ugly.  At the same time, you have to be careful with colors of the same hue as well.  Light gray text is hard to read on a white background (that one is a little more obvious).

This page talks a little about contrast ratios and provides a good tool to check for it:
http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html

They mention that you should shoot for a contrast ratio of 4.5:1 with small text.  Any less than that and you risk the possibility of users having trouble reading your site.

There's another tip I can give.  Whenever you're choosing 2 colors to go next to eachother, pick a boring color that lacks saturation (white, gray, black, or a really dull color) and then pair that up with a color packed with lots of saturation (blue, orange, red, green, etc).  In general, this will look better than trying to put two exciting colors next to eachother in the same design (unless you're designing a comic book site).

And then this site has a cool gallery where you might find some inspiration and good color combinations:
http://www.cwd.dk/

But I'll tell you that my methods have changed drastically since I first started out.  A little creativity is good, but I now place more importance on usability than anything.  I try to keep every design I do simple and usable... kinda like Stackoverflow.  I only mention that because my focus on usability tends to influence my design decisions.

A couple of my favorite sites on usability and optimization are 
http://www.useit.com/ and
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you are programming for some platform it is better to follow that particular platform's guidelines. (And not to alter system colors without a reason)

If you are programming for the web you might appreciate following a theme from some major web-application, such as gmail.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this one in the past:

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

I would recommend turning on the tooltips (go to `'About & Help' > 'Show Tooltips'`) so you can see the descriptions of the different types of color schemes offered when you hover over them.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your users.  Just that.  Just ask them, and take their advice.  They're the ones who'll have to be staring at the color scheme for hours or days on end; take their advice.

Update:  I'm not suggesting that you give your users the complete range of options; the way this usually works is with a small group of users, generate a few styles of the site that seem reasonable, and ask the small group to pick the one they like the best.  That way, there's a coherent look to things, but you still get user input from your end users.

Comment: :( See comments on Smandoli's post

Answer (score 2):

Personnally, I'm a big fan of UI Frameworks like DevExpress which implements skin technology. So, the user has the possibility to switch to his favorite look. For us, it is just five lines of code and our users are always satisfied to have this option. Vista, Office 2003, Office 2007 are just a small set of different options offered to our customers.

Comment: +1 I have become such a fanboy of DevExpress since I have started using their products.  I love the skinning tool as I now no longer have to deal with the issues Refracted Paladin is talking about anymore.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I can see this phenomenon inside in my company with our internal product using DevExpress. Some employees are using the Vista style, Office 2003 style or DevExpress custom styles. I never got a complain about the look and feel of our application.

Comment: One of the places I used to work, one of the guys in the office would reset his system colors every couple of weeks. This was under Win3.1, so the "system" colors really controled *everything*. He came up with some really ugly combinations....

Answer (score 2):

Give your users the most bizarre bling colour scheme
(like a combination of purple, green, glaring red, pink)
and you will be assured of a deluge of suggestions from your users.

Even though your colours are bizarre, you have to ensure that the pages are still technically usable but aesthetically unbearable. Ensure the words and widgets are visible so that lettering should use darker colours like crimson, blue or dark grey on light coloured backgrounds. Pastel the background so that they won't impede the user's sight.

If you wish to defend the reputation for your taste of colours, place a "Contact web master" link which leads to a disclaimer saying your colour scheme is deliberate because you are forcing users to design and submit and vote on a colour scheme. Why not write a cheap lil' web app to facilitate the voting too?

Comment: creative and sneaky, I like it!

Answer (score 1):

I take you have some users.  I suggest asking them what they would like in colors.

Aside from that, to deliver data effectively you have to keep visual clutter to a minimum.  Gray is a time-tested agent for helping with that.

I see from your comment that gray is despised.  Well, you could spell it "grey" -- British-isms are are classic chic.  Seriously, you need to go for three pastels in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for posting and I mean no offense but that is exactly what got me to here.  Out of our 200 ish users 175 are Nurses or Social Workers and 75% of them middle aged or older who can't agree what font size I should use let alone what color scheme to follow.  I believe the last direction I recieved on this was "Make it pretty!"

Comment: Also, the last thing I made using dominantly gray's was laughed at; not out of meanness but because they thought I was making a joke!

Comment: Ha ha!  Thanks for the context.  It seems your best approach would have been to not let them know UI design does have options.  But that's just hindsight.

Comment: Too right there!! Oh well, I will know for the next project!

Answer (score 1):

I would say stick to what you're comfortable with and make them grayscale but just add hints and accents of colour.

[Adobe Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) is a good tool for which colours to use.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with greyscale, and use colours only when they can have some meaning. E.g., use bright red for negative dollar amounts, blue for email addresses, bold black text on a yellow background for phone numbers, etc. This sort of thing really helps users find their way around your app, especially when there is alot of information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [AVIVADirectory.com](http://www.avivadirectory.com/color/)

> "The Canonical List of Online Color Resources for Designers
>   (updated periodically with neat stuff)"

Just a massive list of links and resources about pretty colours.
*And lets just agree to disagree on the 'u' in colour, ok ; )*

Also, a +1 for [colorschemedesigner.com](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) mentioned earlier by John Rasch

Answer (score 1):

I asked some friends on the Internet who pretty much represent the userbase for my apps. The general consensus is that certain shades of blue and cyan are nice. Not entirely unlike the default in MSN Messenger 8.5. I then used that to colorize what started as grayscale.

That's where I get my ideas.